# Cannot open resources where filename contains a colon

Tags: java, classloader

I have a weird issue that I'm experiencing on my laptop;

**Laptop**:
OSX
Version: 10.11.6 - El Capitan

**Java**:
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

I'm trying to use `ClassLoader#getResource` to open a filename of the following format `app-2016-08-13T22:55:00Z.1.log.gz`.

I've placed the file under */src/main/test/resources* however I am always getting back `null`.

If I rename the file to be anything without the colons the code works.
What's going on?

```
@Test
public void testColonFile() throws Exception {
    String resourceFilename = "app-2016-08-13T22:55:00Z.1.log.gz";
    InputStream is = TestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceFilename);
    //InputStream is null here!
 }
```

Comment: I suggest removing `toURI()`.

Comment: There are a lot of discussions about HFS+ and colons. The thing is the `:` was used as a filepath delimiter. So you should avoid to use `:` in filenames.

So, the **system just can't find specified file**

See also: here is the [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations) with comparison of filesystems and their limitations.

Comment: Your code is invalid. Resources are not files. They can be in a JAR or WAR file, not in the file system. You should use the URI directly, or `getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: if I use just `new File(absolutePath)` it works fine. So it can clearly find it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `toURI` is URL-encoding the colon, and the constructor to `File` is not expecting that.

Please add a line like

```
System.err.println(Resources.getResource(resourceFilename).toURI());
```

to see.

Comment: It is failing before the `toURI` . `InputStream is = BlingPublisherTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceFilename);` is also returning null for an inputstream